# Approximate analytic solution to a polynomial equation

Tags: equation-solving, approximation

The analytic solution of the equation
$$
1-\frac{2M}{r}+\frac{Q^2}{r^2}-\frac{\Lambda}{3}r^2 = 0
$$
obtained by using the code

```
Solve[1 + Q^2/r^2 - (2 M)/r - (r^2 Λ)/3 == 0, {r}]
```

is lengthy and complicated.

How can one verify that two approximate solutions obtained by retaining terms only up to first order in $\Lambda$ and $Q^2$, which are small quantities, are
$$
r_1 = 2M - \frac{Q^2}{2M} + \frac{4M}{3}(2M^2-Q^2)\Lambda, \\
r_2 = \sqrt{\frac{3}{\Lambda}} -M - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}(3M^2-Q^2)\sqrt{\Lambda}
$$

Comment: 1. "…only up to first order of $\Lambda$ and $Q^2$", I think you mean $Q$? 2. Is $M>0$ ?

Comment: 1.  ...second order in $Q$. 2. Yes, all quantities are positive.

Comment: something like that? `Series[r /. 
     Solve[1 + Q^2/r^2 - (2 M)/r - (r^2 \[CapitalLambda])/3 == 
        0, {r}][[4]], {Q, 0, 2}] // Normal // 
  Series[#, {\[CapitalLambda], 0, 1}] & // 
 FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> {M > 0}] &
`

Comment: @chris It looks like an answer.

Answer (score 4):

This provides the second solution it seems.

```
 Series[r /. Solve[1 + Q^2/r^2 - (2 M)/r - (r^2 Λ)/3 == 0, {r}][[4]],
 {Q, 0, 2}] //  Normal // Series[#, {Λ, 0, 1}] & //
  FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> {M > 0}] &
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
eqn = 1 + Q^2/r^2 - 2 M/r - r^2 Λ/3 == 0;

soln = Assuming[{Q > 0, M > 0, Λ > 0},
   Solve[eqn, r] // Simplify];
```

Verifying that `soln` satisfies the equation

```
eqn /. soln // Simplify

(*  {True, True, True, True}  *)

approx = Assuming[{M > 0, Q > 0, Λ > 0}, 
  Series[r /. soln, {Λ, 0, 1}, {Q, 0, 2}] //
    Normal // 
   Simplify]

(*  {Q^2/(2 M), -(Q^2/(2 M)) + (8 M^3 Λ)/3 + 
  M (2 - (4 Q^2 Λ)/3), -((-3 Sqrt[3] M^2 Λ + 
   8 M^3 Λ^(3/2) + 
   2 M Sqrt[Λ] (3 - 2 Q^2 Λ) + 
   Sqrt[3] (6 + Q^2 Λ))/(
  6 Sqrt[Λ])), (-3 Sqrt[3] M^2 Λ - 
  8 M^3 Λ^(3/2) + Sqrt[3] (6 + Q^2 Λ) + 
  2 M Sqrt[Λ] (-3 + 2 Q^2 Λ))/(
 6 Sqrt[Λ])}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

As Mathematica can find an analytic solution in this case, I believe we can have greater confidence in approximation to the exact solution rather than an exact solution to an approximate equation.  In general, the roots of a polynomial are notoriously ill-conditioned: a small change in the coefficients can cause a large change in the roots.

I provide a solution that is simultaneously first order in `Q^2` and `Λ`, so there is no term in `Λ Q^2`.  I introduce the dummy variable e to facilitate this approximation.

```
soln = Solve[1 + Q^2/r^2 - (2 M)/r - (r^2 Λ)/3 == 0, {r}];
approxsoln = 
  Assuming[M > 0 && Λ > 0, 
   Map[Series[#, {e, 0, 1}] &, soln /. u : (Λ | Q^2) -> e u, {3}] // 
    FullSimplify];
result = Normal[approxsoln] /. e -> 1 // InputForm

(*{{r -> Q^2/(2*M)}, {r -> 2*M + (8*Λ*M^3)/3 - Q^2/(2*M)}, 
 {r -> -(Sqrt[3]/Sqrt[Λ]) - M + (Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[Λ]*M^2)/2 - (4*Λ*M^3)/3}, 
 {r -> Sqrt[3]/Sqrt[Λ] - M - (Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[Λ]*M^2)/2 - (4*Λ*M^3)/3}}*)
```

Comment: $\Lambda$:  [Esc] [Shift]-L [Esc]  or  `\[CapitalLambda]`

Comment: @EricTowers: Thanks - I know how to do it Mathematica, but not on the website.

Comment: In markdown, cut-and-paste one copy of the one you see in my comment, remove any whitespace that might have appeared, then cut-and-paste it wherever you need it.  (The challenge is getting *one*.  Once you have one, it's easy to make copies...)  Doing this for the one you see above:  `Λ`